# Gallery Widget within a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-gallery, google-tv

I would like to implement a list view that contains a series of thumbnails on each row.  I have tried a list view with embedded gallery widgets.  It's not working, nothing is being displayed.  Just wondering if I'm on the right path, or should I use a different widget for this layout.

Row 1:  Image1 Image 2 Image3 
Row 2:  Image1 Image 2 Image3 
etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by creating a scroll view that contained a linear layout.  In my code I programmatically added HorizontalScrollView objects, found here: https://github.com/vieux/Android-Horizontal-ListView.  Thanks

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fillViewport="true"> 

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/listLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">    
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting horizontal scroll view inside list view.

Comment: A horizontal scroll view doesn't take an adapter and I don't know the number of thumbnails that will appear on each row, any other ideas?

Comment: I don't think there is any other way, you will have to create custom horizontal scrolling list view. Try looking up on google, I am sure some great mind must have already done it.